# How do I determine if a ROS robot is going frontwards or backwards?

Tags: ros, quaternions

ROS provides an odometry message, which tells me the following in reference to an xy plane.

- The x component of the robot’s speed in (m/sec).
- The y component of the robot’s speed in (m/sec).
- The robot’s angular orientation represented as a quaternion (z and w components in radians)

ROS provides the following additional C++ libraries

- Quaternion API:
  http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html
- Vector 3 API: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Vector3.html

I have an inelegant giant if-statement that uses the quadrant the robot is facing together with the direction of the x and y components. I would rather learn how to leverage quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a need to work with quaternions here. The problem seems much simpler.

From [`nav_msgs/Odometry`](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html): "The twist in this message should be specified in the coordinate frame given by the `child_frame_id`".

So the twist expresses velocity (both linear and angular), with respect to `child_frame_id`. In most robot setups, `child_frame_id` will be a coordinate frame fixed to the robot, for example "base_link". So the velocity in the twist is given with respect to a frame fixed to the robot -- you can simply check if the vector in `twist.linear` is pointing towards the positive half plane, something like:

```
if (odom_msg.twist.linear.x >= 0.0 && odom_msg.twist.linear.y >= 0.0)
    // robot going forward
```

Comment: When I publish a cmd_vel message requesting a x linear velocity of 0.2 m/s and a z angular velocity of 0.2 radians/sec the robot travels in a circle. The odometry frames have a frame_id of odom and a child_frame_id of base_link. when the robot is facing 0 degrees the x and y speeds are (2.0,0.0). At 45 deg (0.15, 0.15), at 90 deg (0.0, 2.0), 135 deg (-0.15, 0.15), at 180 (-0.20, 0.0). If I receive x/y speeds of (-2.0, 0) with an angle of 180, it is going forward. If the angle is 0, it is going backward. The signs of x and y speeds are not enough. I need to know which way it is facing.